# HR doesn't appear in proper place

Tags: html, css

Trying to separate my header and navtab with a simple horizontal line. Nothing fancy.

Yet, it appears above the header for some reason. I know it has something to do with floating of twitter button and company logo. Before I did this the line appeared as it should. I'm stuck here.

```css
.main_header {
  background: #d0d0d0
}

.company_logo {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 50px;
}

.twitter {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header class="main_header">
  <div class="company_logo">
    <img src="images/logo.png" width="20%">
  </div>
  <div class="twitter">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/kali"></a>
  </div>
</header>


<hr>

<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="port.html">Portfo</a></li>
      <li><a href="ser.html">Servi</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I fixed your code but there was a script tag in a random place, check if that's not what's wrong.

Comment: "HR at wrong place at wrong time" Welcome to corporate life!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
hr{
  clear: both;
}
```

Should clear floating elements on either side.

Comment: this one helped in certain way ;-) I have horizontal line back but it changed the background colour of the header above the line back to default white.

Answer (score 2):

You're right. Since the children of `.main_header` are floated, their parent has no height.
One solution is to [clear the floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Floats#Clearing_floats).

Below, I'm using `group` class and one of the [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix) methods.
For further reference, see [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/what-methods-of-clearfix-can-i-use)

```css
.main_header {
  background: #d0d0d0
}

.company_logo {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 50px;
}

.twitter {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.group::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<header class="main_header group">
  <div class="company_logo">
    <img src="images/logo.png" width="20%">
  </div>
  <div class="twitter">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/kali"></a>
  </div>
</header>

<hr>

<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="port.html">Portfo</a></li>
      <li><a href="ser.html">Servi</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```